# Quand doit-on utiliser mil au lieu de mille ?

Tags: nombres, indications-de-temps, dates

Pour les dates, on peut souvent lire « l'an mil », ou « le douze Juillet deux mil quatre », il me semble que l'on trouve surtout *mil* dans les comptes rendus et les documents officiels.
Est-ce juste une question de style ou existe-t-il une règle précise pour l'emploi de *mil* ou *mille* ?

Comment: Que pouvons nous retenir?car moi j'écris toujours mil dans les registres d'acte de naissance."Deux mil vingt"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Selon les [Clefs du français pratique de Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=9C49gz80hERY.html) (gouvernement du Canada), *mil* ne peut être utilisé que pour l'écriture des années entre 1001 et 1999, car il vient du latin « *mille* » qui signifie un seul millier. *Mille* vient du latin « *milia* » qui signifie plusieurs milliers. Il ne peut pas être utilisé lorsqu'il n'est pas suivi d'un autre nombre, ni lorsqu'il est précédé d'un multiplicateur (p. ex. *deux mille*).

La [Banque de dépannage linguistique de l'Office québécois de la langue française](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1322) ajoute que *mil* ne peut pas être utilisé pour les années précédant l'ère chrétienne.

Dans tous les cas, l'usage de *mil* est considéré vieilli et n'est jamais obligatoire. *Mille* est donc à privilégier.

Answer (score 9):

Il est dit dans le petit Larousse : « Dans les dates on écrit indifféremment *mille* ou *mil*. ».
Dans la réalité je n'ai vu écrit *mil* que dans l'expression *an mil*. A moins de vouloir écrire dans un style de français ancien, il est sage de n'employer *mil* que pour *an mil*.

Comment: Et encore, [Termium](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=1675.html#zz1669) (lien fourni par Kareen) préconise l'usage inverse : « l'an mille », « l'an mil neuf cents ».

Answer (score 5):

Pour faire simple, j'aurais tendance à dire "jamais". Mille est presque toujours écrit "mille", et j'ai beau chercher, les rares fois où je l'ai vu utilisé étaient dans des textes de notariat, ou des livres type fantasy.

En gros, en tout cas en Français de métropole, "mil" est désuet et très très peu, voire jamais utilisé. Ca peut être différent pour du Québecois cependant.

Seule exception: l'expression "l'an mil", qui doit être orthographiée ainsi et pas "l'an mille".

Comment: Même « l'an mille » peut très bien s'orthographier comme ça. Et [Termium](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=1675.html#zz1669) (lien fourni par Kareen) interdit même « l'an mil » (je me demande pourquoi).

Comment: Oui, ça "peut", mais après, si on voulait respecter l'expression, ça serait "l'an mil"; je suis bien conscient que ça change pas grand chose par contre. Même cas que "a priori" et "à priori" par exemple.

Answer (score 2):

En France "mil" est (encore) systématiquement utilisé par l'administration pour les documents officiels comme les extraits de naissance ou d'état civil

Comment: On dit « extraits d'actes de naissance », pas « extraits de naissance ». « Mil » ne se rencontre que pour les actes indiquant une date du dernier millénaire. « Deux mil » est incorrect car « mil » est l'ancien singulier de mille et « mille » l'ancien pluriel. Voir réponse de Kareen.

Comment: Encore vrai en France en 2017!

Answer (score 1):

Je confirme : "mille" au pluriel, "mil" au singulier et à l'ancien.Comme on est en train de supprimer peu à peu les difficultés de l'orthographe, écrivons mille...

Answer (score 0):

J'ai reçu hier mon extrait d'acte de naissance, il est indiqué *mille* neuf cent qu....-... et non *mil*.

Je lis ici et là que seulement sur les documents administratifs de l'État civil on indique *mil* pourtant sur mon document il a été écrit sous la forme *mille*, par contre, pour mes parents nés 25 ans plus tôt, c'est la forme *mil*. Par conséquent, je pense que *mil* est désuet. On doit mettre *mille* à présent.

Answer (score 0):

J'ai le compte rendu d'un jugement de tribunal Français de 2018. C'est bien écrit "Mil" à la fin. Je pense que seule l'administration continue d'utiliser cette orthographe.

> AINSI JUGÉ ET PRONONCÉ PAR MISE À DISPOSITION AU GREFFE DU JUGE DE
>   L’EXÉCUTION PRÈS LE TRIBUNAL DE GRANDE INSTANCE, LE QUATRE
>   DÉCEMBRE DEUX MIL DIX HUIT.