# D'où viennent les règles complexes des pluriels de vingt, cent, et mille ? Et pourquoi l'an mil ?

Tags: pluriel, nombres

On m'a appris à les appliquer correctement, mais je me demande qui en a décrété ainsi, car je n'en appréhende pas la logique.

Comment: Related: [Quand doit-on utiliser mil au lieu de mille ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1855/217)

Answer (score 6):

Pour la première question : *cents* et *vingts* dans *deux cents* ou *quatre-vingts* sont assez logiques compte tenu des emplois nominaux à la place de *centaine* pour *cent* et de la persistance pour *vingt* de formes vigésimales

> On trouverait des cents et des milliers d'années ? (Lamart)
>   L’hôpital des quinze-vingts
>   …

ils ont finis par être assimilés dans les nombres à multiples à des noms, donc accordés en conséquence, comme par ailleurs *million*, *milliard*…

Ce qui est étonnant c'est au contraire que s'ils sont suivis d'autre numéraux, ils redeviennent invariables. Voire à ce sujet Grevisse

> *Vingt* et *cent*, quoique *viginti* et *centum* fussent invariables en latin, variaient ordinairement autrefois dans les multiples, même s'ils étaient suivis d'un autre numéral. […] Cependant il y avait une certaine tendance à les laisser invaria-bles comme en latin dans toutes les circonstances, jusqu'au XVIᵉs. […]. Cette règle moderne, tout à fait arbitraire, a été d'abord édictée par l'Académie en 1 694 pour *vingt* parce que ce multiple de vingt était devenu une formation isolée (d'où l'agglutination que l'on trouve dans Quatrevingt-treize, titre d'un roman de Hugo […]). La règle sera étendue à *cent* au cours du XVIIIᵉs. : en 1762, l'Ac. écrit encore *neuf **cens** mille.* (Grevisse, 14, 592)

En ce qui concerne *mil*, il ne s'agit pas d'une troncature de *mille*, mais bien de l'évolution du mot latin correspondant à un seul millier

> Pour un seul millier, le latin employait *mille* : de là, en ancien français, la forme *mil* ; pour plusieurs milliers on employait en latin *milia* : de là notre mot *mille*, prononcé autrefois comme dans *famille*, et parfois écrit *milie*. Cependant, dès le XIIᵉs., les deux formes *mil* et *mille* ont été concurremment employées au singulier et au pluriel — la distinction actuelle, fixée par Oudin, est arbitraire; elle s'est imposée au XVIIIᵉs. (ibid)

Answer (score 1):

## Vingt

"*vingt*" s'écrit toujours comme cela sauf dans "*quatre-vingts*" **seulement s'il n'est pas suivi par un autre cardinal numéral et s'il n'est pas un ordinal**. ([Source](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-3211.php))

Exemples :

> 80: quatre-vingts
>
> 85 : quatre-vingt-cinq
>
> 1.980: mille neuf cent quatre-vingts
>
> 80's : les années quatre-vingt

## Cent

"*cent*" prend un '*s*' lorsqu'il n'est pas suivi par un autre nombre.

Exemples :

> 300 : trois cents
>
> 324 : trois cent vingt-quatre

## Mille

"*mille*" est invariable. Quand on parle de "*milles*" il s'agit de l'unité de mesure (1 mille = 1,609 km). Le terme "*mil*" est utilisé lorsque que le nombre est un ordinal et non un cardinal. ([Source](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-mille-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-milles-%C2%BB))

Exemples :

> 1.020 : mille vingt
>
> 3.000 : trois mille
>
> 1910 : [l'An de Grâce] mil neuf cent dix

Comment: Certes, mais là n'est pas la question. Soit dit en passant *mil* n'est en principe plus utilisé, mais il pouvait employé aussi bien pour des ordinaux que pour des cardinaux.